# numpy array slicing to avoid for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I am using `numpy` to do some calculations. In the following code:

```
    assert(len(A.shape) == 2)  # A is a 2D nparray
    d1, d2 = A.shape
    # want to initial G,which has the same dimension as A. And assign the last column of A to the last column of G 
    # initial with value 0   
    G = zero_likes(A)
    # assign the last column to that of G
    G[:, d2-1] = A[:, d2-1]

    # the columns[0,dw-1] of G is the average of columns [0, dw-1] of A, based on the condition of B
    for iW in range(d2-1):
        n = 0
        sum = 0.0
        for i in range(d1):
            if B[i, 0] != iW and B[i, 1] == 0:
                sum += A[i, iW]
                n += 1
        for i in range(d1):
            if B[i, 0] != iW and B[i, 1] == 0:
                G[i, iW] = sum / (1.0 * n)
    return G
```

Is there an easier way using "slicing" or "boolean array"?

Thanks!

Comment: It would save some time to readers if you contextualized your code, saying what is its purpose. Alternatively/additionally, you can comment your code.

Comment: Is the array `A` 3-dimensional? Otherwise `G=A[:,d2-1]` and `G[i,iw]=...` does not make sense. However, if that is true, `sum` would also be a one-dimensional array which does not make sense. Please correct first the bug in the code you show ... do you mean `G=A[:,:d2-1]` ??

Comment: Give us a working sample!

Comment: Thanks. I have added some comments on the code. I think my initialization of G is wrong. The G should have the same dimension as A

Comment: Did you test this code? I doubt that this is doing what you expect because `G = A[:,d2-1]` is still a 1d and not a 2d array! Do you mean `G = A.copy()` and then change the appropriate elements of G? Please provide us with a simple (small) example of `A` and `B` and your result `G` such that we can test our codes!

Comment: I do not have a test example till next week. I have tested your code with similar sample, but only the axis=0 should be changed to axis = 1, since i need the sum of each row. And  the G[:, :-1] = where(m, avg, Gtw[:, :nW-1]) should be changed.

Comment: @plonser, I still do not quite understand the where(m, avg, y), in the document says avg and y need to have the same shape as condition, in your code, assuming with your test sample,  avg  has a shape(9, ), but m has a shape(5,9), how does this work? Thank you

Comment: The keyword is broadcasting, see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want `G` to have the same dimensionality as `A` and then change the appropriate elements of `G`, the following code should work:

```
# create G as a copy of A, otherwise you might change A by changing G
G = A.copy()

# getting the mask for all columns except the last one
m = (B[:,0][:,None] != np.arange(d2-1)[None,:]) & (B[:,1]==0)[:,None]

# getting a matrix with those elements of A which fulfills the conditions
C = np.where(m,A[:,:d2-1],0).astype(np.float)

# get the 'modified' average you use
avg = np.sum(C,axis=0)/np.sum(m.astype(np.int),axis=0)

# change the appropriate elements in all the columns except the last one
G[:,:-1] = np.where(m,avg,A[:,:d2-1])
```

After fiddling a long time and finding bugs ... I ended up with this code. I checked it against several random matrices `A` and specific choices of `B`

```
A = numpy.random.randint(100,size=(5,10))
B = np.column_stack(([4,2,1,3,4],np.zeros(5)))
```

and so far your and my result were in agreement.

Comment: avg = np.sum(C,axis=0)/np.sum(m.astype(np.int),axis=0), the axis should be 1, which will sum the whole row instead of the column. In this way, how should the G[:,:-1] = np.where(m,avg,A[:,:d2-1])  look like?

Comment: @stevenhz : My code is doing what your code is doing including an assumption of what the starting point of `G` is. Your code makes an average along the `axis=0` and not `axis=1`. Correct your code and bring a simple `A` and `B` and the desired result `G`. Then and only then I will try another time to find a solution.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am wrong here. Thank you very much so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start, focusing on the first inner loop:

```
In [35]: A=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

In [36]: B=np.array([[0,0],[1,0],[2,0]])

In [37]: sum=0

In [38]: for i in range(3):
    if B[i,0]!=iW and B[i,1]==0:
        sum += A[i,iW]
        print(i,A[i,iW])
   ....:         
1 4
2 8

In [39]: A[(B[:,0]!=iW)&(B[:,1]==0),iW].sum()
Out[39]: 12
```

I had to provide my own sample data to test this.

The 2nd loop has the same condition `(B[:,0]!=iW)&(B[:,1]==0)`, and should work in the same way.

As one of the comments said, the dimensions of `G` look funny.  To make things work with my sample, lets make zeros array. It looks like you are assigning to selected elements of `G`, the mean of a subset of `A` (`sum/n`)

```
In [52]: G=np.zeros_like(A)
In [53]: G[I,iW]=A[I,iW].mean()
```

Assuming `n`, the number of terms summed for each `iW` varies, it may be difficult to compress the outer loop into a vectorized step.  If `n` was the same, you could pull out subset of `A` that matches the condition, e.g, `A1`, take the mean on one axis, an assign the values to `G`.  With different numbers of terms in the sums, you still have to loop.

It just occurred to me that masked arrays might work.  Mask off the terms of `A` that don't meet the condition, and then take the mean.

```
In [91]: I=(B[:,[0]]!=np.arange(4))&(B[:,[1]]==0)

In [92]: I
Out[92]: 
array([[False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [93]: A1=np.ma.masked_array(A, ~I)

In [94]: A1
Out[94]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[-- 1 2 3]
 [4 -- 6 7]
 [8 9 -- 11]],
             mask =
 [[ True False False False]
 [False  True False False]
 [False False  True False]],
       fill_value = 999999)

In [95]: A1.mean(0)
Out[95]: 
masked_array(data = [6.0 5.0 4.0 7.0],
             mask = [False False False False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Or with `plonser's` `where`:

```
In [111]: np.where(I,A,0).sum(0)/I.sum(0)
Out[111]: array([ 6.,  5.,  4.,  7.])
```